# C++ prints two extra lines

Tags: c++

I started learning c++ and ran into a strange problem. I managed to recreate the error with this

```
while (true){
    std::cout << last_inp << std::endl;
    sleep(1);
    last_inp = std::cin.get();
}
```

what I expect this to do is to wait for an input, print it out and repeat. It does that but after every cycle it prints two additional empty lines. How can I fix this?

Comment: One line is printed by `std::endl`. Then you read and print the newline that was added by you pressing the `Enter` key.

Comment: You're reading single characters, if you're entering a single character then when you read it back you get that character followed by the new line

Comment: Minor side note : std::endl; is almost never needed you can use "\n". Only in rare cases you will need to force a flush to the output and then you use std::endl (which will have a slight performance overhead).

Comment: Minor point: please always post complete code. This problem might be easy enough for us to spot with running it, but in general you want people to be able to run your code as smoothly as possible, without manually inserting includes, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try inputting a longer word to see more clearly, e.g. `hello` – you won't see any output at all as long as you haven't pressed the enter key. Then you'll see your loop running all the characters in `std::cin`'s buffer – however in the buffer itself there's an additional new-line character: the one resulting from you pressing the enter key. This one is fetched by `std::cin.get()` as well and not treated any differently, just that it provokes yet another line break getting output (the first one you notice) followed by the second one from `std::endl` that you added to all the other characters just alike.

You might catch the special case of the new line character and simply ignore it:

```
if(last_inp != '\n')
{
    sleep(1);
    last_inp = std::cin.get();
}
```

Note, too, that it appears somewhat questionable outputting *before* you actually read in a character – if you don't initialise `last_inp` before the loop you even get *undefined behaviour*.

You might possibly want to change the order within the loop:

```
last_inp = std::cin.get();
std::cout << last_inp << std::endl;
```

with sleeping either before, after or in between according to your likes/requirements.